# textbox salvando no banco mesmo estando vazia

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Validação e mensagem:

```
 if (txtFone.Text.Trim() == string.Empty)
 {
      MessageBox.Show("O campo Telefone é obrigatório!");
      txtFone.Focus();
      return false;
 }
```

Código do botão gravar:

```
 if (this.Valida())
 {
            Model.cliente_fisico cliente_fisico = new model.cliente_fisico();
            BLL.cliente_fisico bllCliente_fisico = new BLL.cliente_fisico();
            cliente_fisico.idClientefisico = Convert.ToInt32(lblid.Text);
            cliente_fisico.nome = txtNome.Text;
            cliente_fisico.rg = txtRG.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cpf = txtCPF.Text;
            cliente_fisico.email = txtEmail.Text;
            cliente_fisico.endereco = txtEndereco.Text;
            cliente_fisico.nr = txtNr.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cep = txtCEP.Text;
            cliente_fisico.estado = txtEstado.Text;
            cliente_fisico.telefone = txtFone.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cidade = txtCidade.Text;
            if (cliente_fisico.idClientefisico == -1)
                bllCliente_fisico.Insert(cliente_fisico);
            else bllCliente_fisico.Update(cliente_fisico);
            dgvClienteFisico.DataSource = bllCliente_fisico.Select();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que acontece é que o trecho abaixo nunca será verdade, pois por padrão a mascara é aplicada.

```
    if (txtFone.Text.Trim() == string.Empty) {

        MessageBox.Show("O campo Telefone é obrigatório!");
        txtFone.Focus();
        return false;

    }
```

Então, você tem duas opções, modificar a propriedade `TextMaskFormat` para remover a máscara, selecionando a opção `ExcludePromptAndLiterals` ou você remove os caracteres da máscara na hora da verificação.

**Trocando a propriedade:** 
[image: Propriedade]

**Mudando a verificação:**

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtFone.Text.Replace("-", string.Empty)))
{
        MessageBox.Show("O campo Telefone é obrigatório!");
        txtFone.Focus();
        return false;
}
```

**Lembre-se:** Você deve substituir todos os caracteres da máscara para validar se o usuário informou alguma coisa.

Comment: Deu certo, apareceu a mensagem. Só que agora incluiu sem os pontos e o traço

Comment: Qual o seu padrão de máscara? Altere a sua pergunta e coloque o padrão que eu modifico a resposta para poder salvar com a máscara

Answer (score 0):

Use este condicional funciona directinho

```
//Inicia o metodo aqui 
void VerificarCampos(){

if(txtFone.Text == "")
     {
       MessageBox.Show("O campo Telefone é obrigatório ", "Informação",       MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
txtFone.Focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}//aqui enceras o metodo

//no final chama este metodo antes do select do botao guardar

if (!VerificarCampos()) return;
 Model.cliente_fisico cliente_fisico = new model.cliente_fisico();
            BLL.cliente_fisico bllCliente_fisico = new BLL.cliente_fisico();
            cliente_fisico.idClientefisico = Convert.ToInt32(lblid.Text);
            cliente_fisico.nome = txtNome.Text;
            cliente_fisico.rg = txtRG.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cpf = txtCPF.Text;
            cliente_fisico.email = txtEmail.Text;
            cliente_fisico.endereco = txtEndereco.Text;
            cliente_fisico.nr = txtNr.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cep = txtCEP.Text;
            cliente_fisico.estado = txtEstado.Text;
            cliente_fisico.telefone = txtFone.Text;
            cliente_fisico.cidade = txtCidade.Text;
            if (cliente_fisico.idClientefisico == -1)
                bllCliente_fisico.Insert(cliente_fisico);
            else bllCliente_fisico.Update(cliente_fisico);
            dgvClienteFisico.DataSource = bllCliente_fisico.Select();
        }
```

Comment: incluiu o campo de caracteres da mascara ainda ..